# (Swift) timeIntervalSince1970 stored in Realm with current dateTime, but showing wrong date when it is read?

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, time

```
func getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970()-> Int
    {
        return Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    } 


 let lastLearned = getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970()
 let cardData = "\(cardId):\(newCardLevel):\(lastLearned)"
```

**Note:** Everything except lastLearned is unimportant. lastLearned is where I store current time in TimeIntervalSince1970.

```
let array = cardData.components(separatedBy: ":")
    print("lastlearned : \(array[2])") //result: `2020-02-26 10:28:38.467046+0100`
```

Storing lastLearned in Realm:

```
RealmManager.shared.updateLevel(lastLearned: array[2])
```

Printing date from Realm:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(card.last_learned)!)
        print(date) //result: 2106-02-07 06:28:15 +0000 //HOW?
```

Comment: Why are you using both `NSDate` and `Date`?

Comment: What is the difference? I found this `getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970` on the Internet and didnt mention its NSDate there. Which one should I use?

Comment: With Swift, you must use `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your **getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970** *func* to this

```
func getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970() -> Int {
    return Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
}

let date = getCurrentTimeIntervalSince1970()
debugPrint(date)
debugPrint(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(date)))
```

**Result**

1582711543

2020-02-26 10:05:43 +0000